# Push to MongooseJS Subdoc without creating duplicate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongooseJS schema for `Lists`, where each list contains an array of `ListItems`. Each `ListItem` is just a reference to an `Item` and a flag for `isSelected`. Like this:

```
const ListItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  item: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item' },
  isSelected: Boolean,
});

const ListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [ListItemSchema],
});
```

I'm push an `Item` into a `List` by simply using `$push`.

```
List.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id:listId}, 
    {
       $push: {
         items: {item:itemId, isSelected:false}
       }
    }
);
```

This works, but it allows me to push the same `Item` onto a `List` more than once.

What's the best way to add `Items` in this  kind of structure while checking for duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $ne to avoid duplicate

```
List.findOneAndUpdate( {_id:listId},{items.item: {$ne: itemId}} { $push: { items: {item:itemId, isSelected:false} } });

      `
```

Comment: I've tried that. But it didn't seem to work. Wouldn't `{item:itemId, isSelected:false}` be a new and unique object, even if another item in the list shared that itemId? How can I tell `$addToSet` to key off of the `item` field?

Comment: probably you have to use $ne in first parameter of query like List.findOneAndUpdate(  {_id:listId},{items.item: {$ne: itemId}} 
{
   $push: {
     items: {item:itemId, isSelected:false}
   }
}); it will not able to add duplicate items into array.

Comment: Brilliant! That works perfectly. Thanks. Not exactly your first answer. If you'd like to update, I'll accept it as correct.